# What event is fired when clicking on a download link and the file saving dialog appears?

Tags: javascript, download, dialog, cgi, mime

File is served dynamically, starting the server side script and generating the output is time consuming, sometimes 5-10 sec. I would like to show a "please wait" message near the download link, till the download process really starts. When file saving dialog appears, I would like to make the "please wait" message simply disappear. The download and save dialog is triggered by server side as writing to the standard output of CGI application, and attaching a MIME type "application/force-download" header. Is it possible somehow to track the file download dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `data-disable-with` attribute of html. its simply appear on button click and disappear when server respond back.

Ex.

```
<input type="submit" data-disable-with="Please wait while downloading.." autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Interesting, I have never heard about this attribute, thx. But is it applicable to download links too? I am using "a" elements with "href" attributes.

Comment: Do you have a link to a reference about `data-disable-with`? With Google I found some cases of people advising its use, but not a detailed description of it.

Comment: oh, i haven't tried this attribute with anchor tag, but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Appears to require the [jquery-disable-with](https://github.com/Anduin2017/jquery-disable-with) plugin